# Optional Regex Operation

Tags: python, regex

I am stuck in a regex operation. I am trying to write an optional expression to find date in a string

I have three strings a,b and c as given below

```
a = '(sam was born on 11 Oct 1990)'
b = 'sam was born on Oct 1990'
c = 'sam was born on 1990'
```

I want to write an expression such that for

```
a I get output '11 Oct 1990'
b I get output 'Oct 1990'
c I get output '1990'
```

I am able to fetch the correct output for a and b, but for c I am unable to. However when I change c to

```
c = 'sam was born on  1990' -- with two spaces between on and 1990
```

I fetch the correct output.

The Regex I use is:

```
print re.findall(r"((11)?[\s\(](((Nov|Oct))?([\s\(-]|,\s)(1990|1991)))", a)
```

The Output I fetch is:

```
Output for a : [('11 Oct 1990', '11', 'Oct 1990', 'Oct', 'Oct', ' ', '1990')]
Ouptut for b : [(' Oct 1990', '', 'Oct 1990', 'Oct', 'Oct', ' ', '1990')]
Ouptut for c : []
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: take a look at sites designed to help you designed regex, for instance, regex101.com

Comment: Don't waste your time on online regex sites, especially regexr.com and regex101.com. They are bloated, slow, and loaded with errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
regex = re.compile(r'((?:11)?[\s\(](?:(?:(?:Nov|Oct))?(?:[\s\(?:-]|,\s)?(?:1990|1991)))')
```

It's just the same as yours but with non-capturing blocks, only the outer one captures

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `\s` before the dates. This gives you your desired output.

```
print re.findall(r"((11)?[\s\(](((Nov|Oct))?([\s\(-]|)(1990|1991)))", c)
```

Comment: Hi Borja, Thanks for the response, I gave the (,\s) to handle case like (sam was born on 11 Oct, 1990), where we have a comma after Oct

Comment: You are not specifying that on the post. There's no comas in any of your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (maybe simpler?):

```
on\s([^)\n]+)\)?$
# match on literally
# a whitespace
# followed by anything NOT a closing parenthesis or newline (save this to Group 1)
# followed by an optional parenthesis
# bind the Expression to the end of the line
```

This takes into account the `on` before and an optional `)` after the desired match. You need to use the `multiline` mode, see it [working on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kA4zU7/1).

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this works:

```
str=re.findall(r'([\d]{0,2}\s*?[a-zA-Z]*?\s*[\d]{4}',a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good and clear option:

```
found = re.findall(r"(11\s)?(Nov\s|Oct\s)?(1990|1991)", a)
```

Then if you have multiple dates in string you can just print:

```
for date in found:
    print ''.join(date)
```